# Mac died with error IOUSB family specific matching fails

Tags: macos, mac, usb

I have had this Mac for 6 years or so, always worked perfectly. There has been no new hardware/software for over 3 years.

Two days ago while it was playing itunes, it shut down itself and would not reboot. I have tried a safe boot. It (sometimes) gets through to the normal screen and then the mouse freezes and have to do a hard shut down.

I have disconnected everything apart from the Keyboard and mouse, reset the PRam, reseated the memory and hard drive, still the same problem.

Having looked in the Safe Boot info it seems there is a 'IOUSB Family Specific Matching Fails' that occurs many times.
I cannot even get to be able to start off system OS X disk as it crashes to quickly to get it open.

Help! This is my main music computer at my studio and I cant earn anything with no computer working.

Detailed specs as I know them:

- 2x 2.66Mhz Dual core processor.
- OS X 10.4.11.
- 2GB 667 MHz DDR FB-DIMM

Anyone with any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you have had hardware failure.  It sounds like the USB Hub device is not working.  This could either because it simply stopped working or because a device connected to the Hub is causing the failure ( although unlikely since you removed all connected devices ).  I hope you have backed up your files because replacement hardware will be a problem.

Comment: 1) Some quick searching the web shows that the message `IOUSB family specific matching fails` also occurs on PCs which have no problem booting. It might not be the main problem.  2) Does the Mac boot in target mode (so you can at least get all the files off) ?

Comment: Hi thanks for those, The files are backed up (and mostly on other hard drives). It will only boot in Safe Mode (and then only for a minute or so before Freezing/switching off). Do you happen to know off-hand if its easy to replace an internal USB Hub? Andy